# Why does the ping programs print so slowly?

Tags: networking, proxy, iptables, ping, icmp

I have a raspberry pi as my gateway at 10.0.0.2 with some custom `iptables` rules for transparent proxy. My Netgear router is 10.0.0.1 with DHCP disabled.

Internet access like browsing the web works just fine. But when I ping from my macbook, the `ping` program stucks at the following line for about 30s. (Sounds like a timeout parameter?)

```
$ ping -v -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
```

However, I can see the ICMP reply message returned almost instantly from a wireshark capture, (including an ICMP Redirect from the raspi, if that's relevant) as shown below. Notice that the second column (1064.xxx numbers) is time. I am interpreting that as it took about 0.04 second for the reply to arrive at my macbook.

[image]

Nevertheless, the `ping` program only continues to print out the following ping result (including a Redirect message) after around 30s, as mentioned above.

```
$ ping -v -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from 10.0.0.2: Redirect Host(New addr: 10.0.0.1)
Vr HL TOS  Len   ID Flg  off TTL Pro  cks      Src      Dst
 4  5  00 0054 63cd   0 0000  3f  01 fd9e 10.0.0.46  8.8.8.8

64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=23.504 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 23.504/23.504/23.504/0.000 ms
```

Comment: Your RPi is telling your client NOT to use it as the router. It's telling your client to use the Netgear instead. I don't think you have your RPi set up quite right for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Spiff Yeah I sort of understand what the redirect message means, but just don't know how to debug further. Also it seems weird that the reply message has arrived but the ping program just does not print it. Is this related to RPi as well?